# Ruby associations without Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

In Rails it's very easy to do things like User.first.monkeys.first.uncle, etc.

How could I get at this awesomeness without Rails and without a database? I noticed there's ActiveModel, but as far as I can tell it doesn't have any support for associations.

I'd like to be able to do things like this:

```
foo = Foo.new

foo.bars
# => []

foo.add_bar(:a => 'a')
foo.bars
# => [#<Bar @attr={:a=>'a'}>]

foo.bars.first.bazs
# => []

foo.bars.first.add_baz(:b=>'b')
foo.bars.first.bazs
# => [#<Baz @attr={:b=>'b'}]

foo.bars.first.foo
# => [#<Foo>]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use an [in-memory database with ActiveRecord and SQLite](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2009/03/15/activerecord-sqlite-in-memory-db-without-rails)? You don't need to import all of Rails just to use the ORM. You could also use an alternative like [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) or [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) depending on your preferences.

Comment: ActiveRecord requires a database, the question says "without a database"

Comment: Indeed, it does, but this was before I knew about 'in-memory' databases =]

Comment: I interpreted "without a database" as "without a database server" which usually excludes SQLite since is a sort of embedded server with a persistent database file. Using in-memory mode means there's no persistent database.